# Conditional formatting of a column based off having any text in the first column of the same row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm not sure if this is even possible without going to VB, but I was trying to do it through conditional formatting.  Basically I have a column (Column K) that will always be the same value (345) if there is a record entered in that row.  Basically when I populate my reports I simply want the value (345) to be entered into Column K if there is any data in that row. I was trying to just use Column A as a reference.  I was messing with `=IF(ISTEXT(Col.A location),"345","")` but that's getting nowhere.  So, I'm looking for ideas outside of vba, but if there are no possibilities then vba is the way to go I suppose. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in columns A to J, and that it starts in row 2, enter this in K2 and copy down as necessary:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2:J2),345,"")
```

Edit: For a conditional formatting formula you don't need the "If" part, because the formatting is already ... conditional:

=COUNTA(A2:J2)

Comment: If I put this in a single cell(or even if I drag it through thne entire range of Column K on my template sheet) it works. If I try to enter it in as a conditional formatting for Column K it does not. The biggest issue I run into with entering it into a cell and dragging it through the rest of the column is that the way my reports are generated I insert the rows of data from the master sheet onto a copy of the template sheet. I don't actually pull the column in question from the master sheet, though so I can't use formatting on the master to pull it to the destination.

Comment: I added a formula for the conditional formatting to my answer.  Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","345")`

Comment: For some reason this wreaks havoc on my workbook. I had to kill excel when I put this on my template and then tried to run my macro to pull a report. *shrug*

Comment: So sorry to hear that. I've used it successfully many times in the past, so my apologies that it didn't work for you.

Comment: I'm not really sure why either; I was messing with ISBLANK and ISTEXT both and wasn't having any trouble earlier. Maybe excel is telling me I need to go home early?

Answer (score 0):

This code works to tell whether column A has something in it or not COUNTA(INDIRECT("$A$"&ROW()))>0, but I don't think you can set the value of the cell using conditional formatting. But with conditional formatting you have to know ahead of time how far down your data is going to go unless you just put it in all the rows.

Why don't you just put it in your VBA code when you are copying, you can find out what the last row is then put the IF() formula in. You can use this code:

```
Dim r1 As Range
Set r1 = Range("K1")
r1.NumberFormat = "General"
r1 = "=IF(COUNTA(INDIRECT(""$A$""&ROW())>0,""345"","""")"
r1.AutoFill Destination:=Range(r1, r1.Offset(200))
```